# Бесплатные программы проектирования ERD

Tags: проектирование

Какие есть бесплатные быстрые программы под windows(для коммерческого использования) аналогичные sybase powerdesigner для проектирования ERD диаграмм.
Где можно добавить таблички и типы данных в них и указать связь между полями и таблицами, а также быстро сделать экспорт в картинку.

Типа таких:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что «[вопросы о том, где найти программы, библиотеки, учебники по программированию и администрированию — не стоит задавать](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)».

Comment: Ну вопрос какие программы есть с указанным функционалом, а не где их искать.

Comment: ознакомьтесь, пожалуйста, с правилами сайта. первую из ссылок я привёл выше. следующая: [Какие вопросы лучше не задавать?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), а далее всё из [Как задавать вопросы](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/asking).

Comment: Опять не вижу ничего такого в правилах.

Comment: извините, у меня нет времени на разъяснения. обратитесь, пожалуйста, в [чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=ru.stackoverflow.com) или поищите ответ на [мете](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/). начать можно [отсюда](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/983)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL Workbench https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/ может не только диаграммы делать, но и реальную БД по диаграммам

Answer (score 3):

Есть [**PgModeler**](http://www.pgmodeler.com.br/), исключительно для **PostgreSQL**, максимально заточенный под его абстракции: отдельные схемы, табличные пространства, собственные типы и прочее.

Он умеет держать соединение с реальной БД, вычислять изменения по сравнению с состоянием базы и экспортировать результаты в базу, SQL-файл или в картинки.

[image: скриншот]

А вот модель распространения у него **крайне бредовая**:

- **Формально** он *бесплатен* и его код открыт под GPLv3, его можно скачать и собрать самостоятельно в любой момент без каких-либо юридических последствий. Процесс сборки из-за кучи зависимостей довольно суров, но осуществим.
- **Фактически** бинарные сборки проекта распространяются "за пожертвования" и отыскать их непросто. Для Linux, например, они есть в репозиториях PGDG, и доступны для свободного скачивания всем желающим.